# Programmatically sent SMS not showing in Messages app

Tags: android, sms

I am sending SMS in a background service using the following code:

```
SmsManager smsManager;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    smsManager = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(0);
} else {
    smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
}

String msg = "message body";
PendingIntent sentPI;
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);

smsManager.sendTextMessage(01XXXXXXXXX, null, msg, sentPI, null);
```

This successfully sends the SMS. But it doesn't show in the default Messages app. The receiver is getting the SMS perfectly. It just doesn't show up in the senders messaging app.

I am using Huawei nova 3i with android version 9.

Comment: Did you perhaps set your app as the default SMS app?

Comment: @MikeM. No. My app cannot be set as default SMS app. The built-in Messages app is set as the default one.

Comment: Hmm, then I would have to guess that it's some weird Huawei thing. On standard Android, since KitKat, any app that is not the default app has its outgoing messages automatically written to the Provider by the system. Are you absolutely certain that it never shows up? Did you try rebooting, just to check? Are you sure that the built-in doesn't have any filters set that might be ignoring your SMS messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there are hundreds, if not thousands, of SMS clients. None have to show SMS messages sent by other apps. They *can* do that, but they do not *have* to do that.

Second, it is possible that on some devices, the device manufacturer chose to not have `SmsManager` add its messages to the system-supplied `ContentProvider` that many (most?) SMS clients use.

IOW, while many times an `SmsManager`-sent message will appear in an SMS client, do not assume that this will happen 100% of the time.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to force the system to add messages from SmsManager?

Comment: @ZakariaAhmed: Not really. If you are the user's designated SMS client, you could add the messages to the `Sms` provider yourself, if they do not show up automatically. In this case, you do not appear to be an SMS client, so that is not an option. If the device manufacturer chose not to put SMS messages from `SmsManager` in the `Sms` provider, that is the device manufacturer's choice -- you do not get a vote. Similarly, if the SMS client chooses to only show its own SMS messages, that is the developers' choice to make.